# Prolog Tail call optimization for flattening a tree

Tags: prolog, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

I want to flatten a tree in prolog using tail recursion.I have done it with append list with recursive calls. I want to optimize my version. This is my function which uses recursive call.I want to make it tail call optimized.

```
fl_t(lf(A),[A]).
fl_t(tr(A,B,C),S4):- fl_t(A,X1),fl_t(C,X2),append(X2,[Y],X3),append(X3,X1,S4).

Input : fl_t(lf(a),Result)
Output : Result=[a]

Input : fl_t(tr(lf([1, 2]), 3, leaf([4, 5])),Result)
Output : Result = [[1,2],3,[4,5]]
```

Can anyone help me please.I am new to prolog. TIA

Comment: Missing `B = Y` - at least

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually flattening. This would do so:

```
fl_t(T, Xs) :-
   phrase(fl(T), Xs).

fl(lf(A)) --> [A].
fl(tr(A, B, C)) -->
   fl(A),
   [B],
   fl(C).
```

That is as tail-recursive as it could be.

Comment: How can I do it by making use of accumulator instead of the phrase function. Thank you :)

Comment: @billwilliams: Say `listing(fl)` to get the expansion.

Comment: But... DCGs like above are present in virtually any Prolog!